# How do I use the empty variable in MySQL more than once?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to check for 2 empty variables in a MySQL statement but I can seem to get the syntax quite right for it. Here is what I have now and it keeps giving me an error. Can anyone please tell me how I can do this properly?

```
  SELECT threads, userid, username, usergroupid
    FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "user
   WHERE  
    " . iif(!empty($exuserids), "AND userid NOT IN ($exuserids)") . "
    " . iif(!empty($exgroups), "AND usergroupid NOT IN ($exgroups)") . "
ORDER BY threads DESC 
   LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT threads, userid, username, usergroupid
    FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "user
   WHERE 1 = 1 
    " . iif(!empty($exuserids), "AND userid NOT IN ($exuserids)") . "
    " . iif(!empty($exgroups), "AND usergroupid NOT IN ($exgroups)") . "
ORDER BY threads DESC 
   LIMIT 1
```

There needs to be a WHERE clause before you specify "AND ..." - the `1 = 1` will be optimized out.  It's a trick used for dynamic SQL to make WHERE clause concatenation easier.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you. I learned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

Well no wonder it gives you an error. Are you using PHPkit or something else that gives you `iif` Because, despite you do not say so, the above is written in PHP and `iif` is not part of the language.

Now, even if you have it why not compile the statement prettily -- gather the conditions in an array, implode with AND and add a WHERE condition if it's not empty.

Finally, having variables in queries is a recipe for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: The conditions are already in a settings array. I just want to check if they are empty or not and only run them if they have anything other than 0 in them.

Comment: The iif is a function in vbulletin.

`code`
 function iif($expression, $returntrue, $returnfalse = '')
{
 return ($expression ? $returntrue : $returnfalse);
}